# Primary MacAddress of Network Devices to update

Tags: networking, snmp

I have developed an SNMP scanner for my college project. It will scan all the SNMP devices connected to the network and store the information to the inventory. I have successfully done the basic scanning of System properties, Interfaces and Device specific properties.

I have a periodic schedule to do `SNMPWalk` over the network again to update the inventory. I am formulating a way to update already scanned devices without creating duplicates in the inventory.

As of now, I have planned to use Physical address of the interface (Network adapter) to update the device apart from hostname.

OID to fetch PhysicalAddress for interface,

```
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6
```

But the problem is, obviously there would be multiple interfaces which might result in multiple PhysicalAddress. 
Usually, If I want to take a computer's `MacAddress`, I will take MacAddress for the network adapter whose `IPEnabled` is `true`. 
But here I am not able to arrive at some Primary `MacAddress` to use for update the device.

I have planned to go with use the first MacAddress in the list of Interfaces as of now, which is a workaround and not obviously a better solution, then hostname of the device for update.

Any suggestions on this?